QGIS: Make larger symbols appear behind smaller symbols from the same layer
Points from a point dataset (delimited text file) are shown with graduated colors and graduated size. The symbology setting is as in figure A. The points overlap each other according to their listing order in the source file (B-1). Preferrably, larger symbols should be behind smaller symbols (B-2). This is achieved by displaying the same layer as three individual layers whereas each of these layers carries one of the symbols (C). Is it feasible to make larger symbols appear behind smaller symbols from the same layer?


Have you looked at the "Control feature rendering order" checkbox under Layer Rendering, at the bottom of the Symbology page?

You need to go to the "Layer Rendering" section at the bottom of the Layer Styling panel, check the "Control feature rendering order" box and clich on the sorting icon on the right to input the rendering order of your feature.
Read this for more information


The suggestion is good, but note: the order indicates the drawing order, not the priority order. If you want the small blue triangle to be drawn on top of the yellow and red triangle, it must be the last one so that it is drawn last.

This should be possible by enabling the "Symbol Levels". You can activate them in the Layer Symbology in the bottom right corner in the "Advanced" menu. Give the symbols you want to see on the top (in your case blue triangle) the highest number and the symbol on the bottom the lowest. For Example:

The result should show something like this:

Check here for more info.
